# How to hide specific menus in WordPress for users not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

As I am new to WordPress I do not know how to show/hide menus by checking the session for users as logged in or not. Where would I write the logic (PHP code) for this?

Comment: hey dude @Andrew Lott 
any answer?

Comment: Solved the problem...


<?php
session_start(); // start your session..

// Condition to check the user is logged in or not...

 if(!isset($_SESSION["del_log"]) && empty($_SESSION["del_log"])){?>


// Jquery to Hide the menu by its id...
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu-item-76').css('display', 'block');
    $('#menu-item-76').css('height', '0px');
});
</script>`


<?php }
?>

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that what the [is_user_logged_in()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) function is for?